# How to view the content of neo4j's transaction log in text format?

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j's transaction log files (neostore.transaction.db.*) are in binary format. What tool or method should I use to see the neo4j transaction logs in text format?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Neo4j transaction log](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/) files are not intended to be humanly readable.

Instead, transaction log files are *data files* used by the neo4j server to keep track of write operations so that after a server crash the database state can be recovered.